# drupal 7 ajax_deliver not working

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal, drupal-7

Does anyone have experience with ajax in drupal 7?
I'm a little stuck.

So, with my module, I output a link and map the path to a callback function with hook_menu()

In the callback function I used ajax_command_replace() and ajax_deliver() to update content.

Well, so far, so good. It all works. But turns out, for complicated reasons, that using links won't work.

So instead I decided to try the jQuery ajax way. So I attach a click event to a div so when it gets clicked something like this runs in a JavaScript file that I load:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://path/etc',
});
```

Then, in my module, I use hook menu to map the path to a callback function that looks like this:

```
function the_callback($var) {
    // a lot of code that gets the right nid to load. This all works...
    // and eventually I end up here:

    $node = node_load($nid, NULL, false);
    if ($node) {
        $node_view = node_view($node); 
        $output = theme("node",$node_view);

        $commands = array();
        $commands = ajax_command_replace('#content','<div id = "content">' . $output . '</div>';
        $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
        ajax_deliver($page);

    }
```

This is the exact same code that was sucessfully replacing content when I had the links. But for some reason this doesn't work when I try to invoke the ajax call with jQuery. The callback function gets called, the correct stuff gets loaded in $output, but the page isn't updating.

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a closing parenthesis?

```
$c = ajax_command_replace('#content','<div id = "content">' .$output. '</div>';
```

Should be:

```
$c = ajax_command_replace('#content','<div id = "content">' .$output. '</div>');
```

Comment: Oh, if only it was something that easy.

Answer (score 0):

probably there is some javascript code inside the $output returned by theme('node', $node_view) , which you need to strip(remove).
here's some code from my ajax function returning the node rendered content:

```
  $n = node_load($nid, NULL, FALSE);
  $output =  drupal_render(node_view($n));
  $output = preg_replace('~<script\s+type="text/javascript">.+</script>~is', '', $output);
```